# Dynamic content using jQuery that includes all the scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to link all my pages together and display only contents of one page in another, including all the scripts. is was using the .load() function but I was told that it does not include the scripts and I also had to use the angularJS input in one page to the other so I tried this:

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {                 // User clicks nav link
  e.preventDefault();                                // Stop loading new link
  var url = this.href;                               // Get value of href

  $('nav a.current').removeClass('current');         // Clear current indicator
  $(this).addClass('current');                       // New current indicator
  $('#container').remove();                          // Remove old content
  $('#content').load(url + ' #container').hide().fadeIn('slow'), function(){
//these are all the scripts in the pages:
$.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
$.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js');
    $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzkXXGUHTJkR86sa0L4CrpmFmytuKWJ8k&callback=initMap');
    $.getScript('js/geolocation.js');
    $.getScript('js/angular-controller.js');
    $.getScript('js/valid.js');
    $.getScript('js/validate.js');
    $.getScript('js/angular-external-data.js');
  }    
});
```

This does not load the scripts either. Any better to include the scripts too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not bundle them and add them normally?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell i did try doing that, it did not work either. I also tried by keeping all those script tags in every page, that didn't work wither.

Comment: i think I'm not understand? why? what is the goal of what you trying to do?

Comment: @Seabizkit this way , i'm trying to make it so that the pages do not have to load every time.

Comment: @ShrijeshSiwakoti i was suggesting that you were doing it wrong but before i jumped to conclusions i thought i would get clarification. Defo remove the onclick. simply having it in the actual view is better than the clicking implementation you were trying. you could have a section in js, which checks if its been loaded before or not. if you were trying to implement a on usage scenario. but loading in main is probably better if your new to this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea in having a single page application is good, but you're doing it the wrong way.

I would do what @Chris Satchell said in his comment and bundle all of your `/js/` files into one `bundle.js`

Then in the `<head>` of your HTML, add all the scripts that you need:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzkXXGUHTJkR86sa0L4CrpmFmytuKWJ8k&callback=initMap"></script>

  <!-- BUNDLED JAVASCRIPT FILE -->
  <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, don't load your components from a url every time the nav bar item is clicked. with all of your scripts loaded once, your page will be a lot faster.

Another bonus to this is that it makes your code a lot easier:

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {                 // User clicks nav link
  e.preventDefault();                                // Stop loading new link
  var url = this.href;                               // Get value of href
  var currentUrl = $('nav a.current').attr('href');  // Get id of current active component

  $('nav a.current').removeClass('current');         // Clear current indicator
  $(this).addClass('current');                       // New current indicator
  $('#' + currentUrl + '-content').hide();              // Hide old content
  $('#' + url + '-content').show();              // Show new content
});`
```

With this as your HTML:

```
<!-- NAV BAR -->
<li><a href="page1">Page 1</a></li>
<li>a href="page2">Page 2</a></li>


<!-- COMPONENTS -->
<div id="page1-content">
  <!-- component stuff -->
</div>

<div id="page2-content" style="display:none">
  <!-- component stuff -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***just conceptual idea of what could be done, but 99% better to load on main page as a bundle.***

This is only worth doing if your js files are huge!!!!!  like where each one is bigger than 500kb and there are lots.
and you do not want to take the penity of loading them if they are likey not to be used.

again only if they are likey not to be used on every visit.

un-tested - just conceptually giving an idea

--Main page

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ... ommited other core script -->

  <!-- ... custome everypage scripts -->
  <script src="/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

--injected views, use something like the below

-------------------------- view start

```
<script>

    var url = '"/views/login.js"'

    if (typeof loginFunctions == 'undefined') 
    {
        //untested but just some code to add file to main page.
        $.loadScript(url, function(){


        });
    }
</script>

 <div>
    some html for the view 
 </div>
```

-------------------------- view end

--scripy login.js
-------------------------- script start

```
//where this only exists here.
var loginFunctions = {

}
```

-------------------------- script end